# Non-public selectors in App?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, non-public-selectors

I'm trying to submit an app via iTunes Connect. Xcode is throwing the following error:

**iTunes Store operation failed.**
The app referenced non-public selectors in Payload/Inflation Calculator.app/Inflation `Calculator: allocBatch:withEntity:count:,allowWithEntity:,` `fastIndexForKnownKey:`, `indexForKey:`

I have no idea what "`non-public selectors`" I would be using, because I stuck pretty close to the book with my code. Anyone have any ideas?

Code for the view controller (only `.swift` in my app):
https://gist.github.com/Calda/aefc2f19bae5f3cf2e54

**EDIT:** As a reference for the future, I confirmed with iTunes Connect Support that this was an issue with iTunes Connect and not a problem with my project. For anyone experiencing this same problem, my best advice would be to wait and try again later.

Comment: It means you using private APIs in your project. It could also be a third party library. Search for the offending method calls and find an alternative solution.

Comment: None of those methods appear in my code and I am not using a third part library. I have no clue where this problem could be stemming from.

Comment: You should contact Apple. I have seen this happening to other devs who have asked this question here at stackoverflow. They contacted Apple and then Apple gave them the reason. The only concern here is: you should double check you don't use any private API for sure.

Comment: What version of `iOS` are you submitting for? And what version of `xcode` are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-public selectors in Payload/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369633/non-public-selectors-in-payload)

Comment: I have the same problem, and I think it might be a server side error because submitting the same file fails first, but consecutive submissions suddenly work. Sometimes it is necessary to **Clean** and **Archive** the project again.

Comment: This issue is just a ***warning*** for me when uploading a build to itunes connect but successfully uploaded, did you encountered this when sending your build to AppStore Review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

**edit: I don't think the first step is needed**

<strike>1) Cleaning the build folder (Hold Alt, Click Product -> Clean)</strike>

2) Deleting the Derived Data (Organizer -> Projects -> Select your project -> Delete Derived Data

Comment: Organizer -> Projects -> Select your project -> Shows Delete Archive and not Delete Derived Data for me! I am using Xcode 9

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I could not submit some of my apps because using non-public selectors. I also tried using Application Loader, but still the same error message

To solve the problem I installed Xcode 6.0.1 - it is still available to download here:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Before installing i moved the old Xcode to trash.

I can now submit any app.

Comment: Since when did we jump `xcode 7`? When did we finish with `xcode 6`? I must be well behind and didn't hear the news that Apple had released `xcode 7` and `xcode 8`.

Comment: Also would it not be best to move on to `xcode 6.1` and not the older version?

Comment: XCode 6.1 *is* the problem.  Apple, in their continuing streak of Breaking ALL The Things when it comes to iOS 8/XCode 6, has made it so some apps get erroneously rejected if they use XCode 6.1 with a pre-iOS 8 deployment target.

Answer (score 2):

For the same app, I got this error today on XCode 6.1. 
I submit the same app (little variation) 2/3 days ago with XCode 6.0.1 without any error! 
Just updated XCode 6.1 and trapped with this error.

I switched back to XCode 6.0.1 and it do not have any problem with the submission. No non-public API usage error. I just download the [dmg](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode#) file and rename xcode.app to XCode_6.0.1. So it coexists with XCode 6.1.

Answer (score 2):

The API differs between iOS 7 and iOS 8.
I got my App validated by switching to Deployment Target "8.0" - built with XCode 6.1.
It might not be the solution to all you guys but you could give it a try.

Might have happened to me because I recently started using UIAlertController -> seems to be an iOS-8-Feature. On iOS 7 this would be UIAlertView. So if you use some nifty new features they might not have been available with previous iOS versions - thus non-public API.

Comment: I did not use UIAlertController. However, my deployment target is 4.3. and I want to go with it :(

Comment: Hey Karim, the UIAlertController was just an example for my case. Maybe you use another API somewhere else that is new (at least newer than 4.3 - do you really have to support iOS 4?). Maybe Apple simply has another problem with XCode 6.1 - with the change described above I was able to keep XCode 6.1 and submit my app.

Comment: In my case, The very same project, all source code are same, can submit with XCode 6.0.1 but not with XCode 6.1

Comment: Upvoted because I think the UIAlertController is probably what's doing it for me.  To be clear, this is *still* a bug: I use UIAlertController, but wrap it in conditionals for whether the user is running iOS 8.  Which, by my understanding, is exactly what you are supposed to do when moving away from a deprecated API.  Moral of the story: Ignore deprecation warnings?!  Thanks Apple, you are so full of win right now...

Comment: If you need to support older version of iOS prior to 8 this solution is not valid. Going back to Xcode 6.0.1 solves the problem

Comment: 6.0.1 is not able to run under my Mac OS.  I'm really hosed now.  I removed the duplicate API calls and it still fails saying they're there; even after i deleted DerivedData

Answer (score 2):

I delete all derived data for xcode projects
/Users/{user_home_folder}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
And app was submitted without any problem

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue that looked like an issue on Apple's end. I submitted the same app (v 1.0.1) yesterday, then rejected it, then submitted again today with a one-line code difference.  Today's submission got rejected for the reason mentioned above.

I was able to solve this, using the latest versions of everything, by changing the version # of my app (e.g. 1.0.1 -> 1.0.2). Think this worked as I had a previous submission sitting in the queue for my older version that I had rejected, YMMV.