# Sprite kit rotateByAngle:aroundAxis:duration: is a non-public selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

After submitting the app. to the store using the Xcode version 8.3 a warning message appears saying:

> The app references non-public selector
>   rotateByAngle:aroundAxis:duration:

What is the public alternative for this selector?

**Edit:**

What if the action returned value of this method sent to the method repeatAction as follow:

```
[SCNAction repeatActionForever:[SCNAction rotateByAngle:10 aroundAxis:SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 0) duration:2]];
```

Does that remove the warning?

[image]

Comment: Look at these to previous questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378484/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-app-name-dec and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476776/non-public-selectors-in-app