# phonegap ios non-public selectors setIsInline error

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using XCode 6.1.1 and upgraded phonegap from 4.2.0 to 5.3.6. After this I started getting this error, while trying to submit to app store.

```
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/app: setIsInline:
```

It was working properly when phonegap version was 4.2.0. I have checked the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476776/non-public-selectors-in-app). But still facing error. I tried to find out where this `setIsInline` method defined, but could not find any references.

Has anyone faced this issue or any pointers to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after these:
- removed all plugins and added again
- downgraded google analytics plugin (https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) to version 0.6.1

I was using Xcode 6.1